# Why counting my zero-scored accepted answer doesn't match that from data.stackexchange?

Tags: support, data-explorer, zero-score-badges

When I count my zero-scored accepted answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3375713) I get 12, but running [how unsung am I query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i) on data.stackexchange gives me just 9. Why is that?

I have seen similar results with [How many upvotes do I have for each tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag) query. For example for python tag, it shows score of 56 on my profile page, but query shows 57. Why is it like this?

The definition of "score" as shown in the tag info says score is number of upvotes minus number of downvotes. This definition agrees with my python upvotes/score values. But strangely, my java score is 39, whereas upvotes as shown in the query is 36. How is this possible?

Comment: SE Data Explorer only updates something like once a week if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Every Sunday at around 3:00 UTC according to http://data.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow Are you suggesting that on Sunday the results of data explorer will be in sync with manual count result?

Comment: they should be, yes

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow then what about the issue inconsistent score/upvote counts, e.g. in java tag for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I'll start with the obvious zero scored accepted answers that don't show in the query:

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36519572/447356) was posted only couple of hours ago, hence still doesn't exist in SEDE data.
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35011654/447356) from January is self accepted, hence doesn't count toward the badge and isn't included in the query on purpose.

This leaves us with one answer that has 0 score, posted before last Monday (when SEDE was updated) and is accepted. After comparing the results from SEDE with [the live list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3375713+isaccepted%3A1+score%3A0), this is the answer: [basic idea of a custom tooltip, using pure Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971637/basic-idea-of-a-custom-tooltip-using-pure-javascript)

Zero score, posted over two months ago, accepted. So why it doesn't appear in SEDE? Because:

> [image]

As you see, it was accepted only three days ago, after SEDE was last updated, hence as far as SEDE is concerned, it's still not accepted.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer, just like a wizard! :D So I think I can extrapolate this idea to my java tag score mismatch too.

Comment: Cheers @Sна and keep running faster than the wind! :-D